# Create new c# project files from code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, automation, projects, envdte

I'm currently working on an application that will generate actual .cs and .xaml code files and add them to a project. I've managed to do this by manually editing an existing .csproj file and thats working well.

However I would like to be able to create the project files from my application as well, to cut out the extra step of creating the project first then running the application after.

Does anyone know how to create a C# project (class library, or WPF Application) from an application? I've looked into DTE, but I've hit a wall

Comment: This may not be what you're looking for, but the C# project files are rather simple MSBuild files, which you can easily generate by hand or with an XmlWriter.

Comment: can you record a macro to do something similar to what you want and use that as your starting point.

Comment: any working solution of this ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't give a complete answer, but maybe I can point you in the right direction.

One avenue to explore in your own searching is MSBuild.  C# and VB.net project files follow the msbuild format, and so the first step in building a valid project file is building a valid msbuild file.

Also, it sounds like you're doing something a little different, but have you looked at the [T4 system](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/Articles/2009/05/01/Visual-Studios-T4-Code-Generation.aspx) for code generation?

Comment: yes, I've looked into T4, but could not figure out how to use it from my application. I was only ever able to make in run inside the visual studio environment. My solution seems easier to me anyways, without needing to learn a new syntax. I will look into this MSBuild idea next